# How to start a new application instance from within the application?

Tags: c#, wpf

When the user clicks a button i want to start a new instance of my application.

When i use this code it throws an error:

```
new Application().Run();
```

> Cannot create more than one System.Windows.Application instance in the same AppDomain.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you give more explanation please what do you mean by show him a new copy of your program?

Comment: Can you be more thorough please, I dont understand your question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have found the solution

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = 
    System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
p.Start();
```

Comment: This doesn't work on .Net Core. For some reason, besides the executable file, when one builds the solution a .dll file is also created with the same name than the .exe file and the call `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;` returns the .dll and not the .exe file. I solved the issue 
assigning the value of `Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName` to the FileName property.

Answer (score 3):

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = Application.ExecutablePath;
p.Start();
```

This is in winforms, but perhaps it's similar in WPF.

Answer (score 2):

With another process:

- Get the program path (e.g. via [`Environment.CommandLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.commandline.aspx))
- [Start a process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx) with said path

Comment: thanks but when i use `app.Run()` give my this error `Cannot create more than one System.Windows.Application instance in the same AppDomain.` this is my code `    Application application = new Application();
      application.Run();`

Comment: @tito11: As i said: It might be prohibited. Create a new process.